# update (edit) user in php

Tags: php, mysql

im a newbie in php and sql programming and can someone help me in my syntax , lately ive been creating this code to edit my user and write it on the database but it always gets an error in oldpassword and password , and it always says password didnt match even if i do it correctly the process , any help on me ? tnx

```
<?php

$update = strip_tags($_POST['update']); 

$username = strtolower(strip_tags($_POST['username']));

$oldpassword = strip_tags($_POST['oldpassword']);

$newpassword = strip_tags($_POST['newpassword']);

$firstname = strip_tags($_POST['first']);

$lastname = strip_tags($_POST['last']);

$gender = strip_tags($_POST['gender']);

$address = strip_tags($_POST['address']);

$zipcode = strip_tags($_POST['zip']);

$contact = strip_tags($_POST['con']);

$email = strip_tags($_POST['mail']);

error_reporting(0);



if($update)
{




if($username&& $oldpassword && $newpassword && $firstname && $lastname && $address && $zipcode && $contact && $email)
{

    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("brightlights") or die(mysql_error());

    $updatecheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM username FROM tb_user WHERE username='$username'");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($updatecheck);
    if($count<=1)
    {

    if($_SESSION['password']==($oldpassword))
    {

    mysql_query("UPDATE tb_user SET
                    username = '$username',
                    password = '$newpassword',
                    Firstname = '$firstname',
                    Lastname = '$lastname',
                    gender = '$gender',
                    address = '$address',
                    zipcode = '$zipcode',
                    contact = '$contact',
                    email = '$email'
                    WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['password'] = $newpassword;
                    $_SESSION['Firstname'] = $firstname;
                    $_SESSION['Lastname'] = $lastname;
                    $_SESSION['gender'] = $gender;
                    $_SESSION['address'] = $address;
                    $_SESSION['zipcode'] = $zipcode;
                    $_SESSION['contact'] = $contact;
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                    session_write_close();
                    echo "Succesfully Updated!";

                }else
                    echo "Password not match!";
            }else
                echo "Username already Taken!";
        }else
            echo "Please fill up all form!";
}
?>
```

Comment: As a side note, your query is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: Plus I think this calls for basic debugging: At which point is the password in the session set? Have you made test outputs of the old and new password? What do they contain?

Comment: your code formatting is terrible.

Comment: Don't use strip_tags on passwords.. actually, don't use it answhere. To prevent XSS it's usually sufficient to use htmlspecialchars() before displaying (the data in the db shouldn't be html-escaped.. you could need it in plaintext emails for example)

Comment: i'm sorry for my code formatting but can you help me fix the problem ? since im a newbie in php programming and this was for my school project

Comment: code formatting WILL help you. it is not for silly decoration. it's most important part of code. It will help you (as well as others) understand what does your code do.

Comment: error_reporting(0); is another thing makes your task harder. Whoever told you to use it is dumb.

Comment: And "this was for my school project" is not an excuse. It doesn't mean everyone should leap to write and debug your code at once.

Comment: instead of criticising other why just dont help them , i'm not a racist but its much appreciated if you help other instead of criticising their errors

Answer (score 0):

```
  if($_SESSION['password']==($oldpassword))
```

But I can't see session_start() after `<?php`

Comment: @RUEL , whenever i try it on my site it always says password didnt match even though i've done or write the old password in my database in the old password field and still i get that password didnt match

Comment: I didn't understand very well but why don't you write $password instead of $_SESSION['password'] ?

Answer (score 0):

I think `$_SESSION['password']` is an encrypted password that doesn't match. Please echo `$_SESSION['password']` and `$oldpassword` and exit, and check their values.